How to get header and footer images in visualforce email templates
I need to add header and footer images to my visualforce email template. I tried uploading from static resource which doesn't work. I don't have the Documents option in my org. Is there any way I can refer the images uploaded in Files or any other solutions for this issue.
Any help on this is really appreciated!
